# Docker Cluster loses leader status after reboot

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, service-discovery

I currently have my docker servers setup on my mac. Unfortunately i had to reboot my mac which apparently caused by docker cluster to lose leader status. Is it possible to do a self promote so that one of the nodes can now be a leader?

```
 ✘ ⚡ root@docker1  ~  docker node ls
  ID                           HOSTNAME             STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
  497ckuujhotoin0a4cqlu3xva *  docker1.example.com  Ready   Active
  49fyll1i5v77nyfmy14x7rw5u    docker4.example.com  Ready   Active
  4i2m25h3aauv002asadfvdxjh    docker6.example.com  Ready   Active
  5050p59139hfa7qs39y4xxxd5    docker5.example.com  Ready   Active
  axahq79bu0yutrfv7pzkuzfny    docker2.example.com  Ready   Active
  d5p49r40rxnzp0htcw8rkophx    docker7.example.com  Ready   Active
  f57q26vzd4e7u7x1oickxwc5l    docker3.example.com  Ready   Active
```

I am using the native docker service discovery that ships with docker 1.12.3

Comment: How did you provision the swarm cluster? Swarm uses etcd to store it state, so you may have lost everything and might need to reprovision.

Comment: What happens if you do a 'docker node promote <id-node>' with any of these nodes?

Comment: I did not use etcd. I used the service discovery that comes with docker swarm

Comment: `docker node promote 49fyll1i5v77nyfmy14x7rw5u` tells me the node has been promoted to manager status but when i do a `docker node ls`, it doesn't show it as reachable or being a leader

Comment: did you rejoin the node first?

Comment: No. All i did was reboot all my servers only to realize the manager servers were no longer showing as reachable. I had to run `docker swarm init --force-new-cluster --advertise-addr 192.168.5.10` to even get `docker node ls` to work.